# displaying iterating numbers without sum

Tags: c++

I am trying to loop my number function from 0 to 9 , but after I want to store to my variable. it sums, but I don't want to have this behaviour. I just want to display the numbers

```c
int Common::digits() {
    int digits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        digits += i;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Comment: Please don't downvote on the subjective opinion of obviousness. In my opinion this question is well-asked.

Comment: The effect of `digits += i` is to add `i` to `digits`, and that happens in each loop iteration, so it computes the sum of the values of `i`.   If you want to display the values instead, there needs to be some other action in the loop body that outputs `i` rather than adding it to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`digits += i;` doesn't *concatente* `i` to `digits`, it sums it.

One way, and surprisingly efficient these days due to the way `std::string` manages its memory, is to use

```
std::string Common::digits() const/*assume class member function*/{
    std::string res;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        res += std::to_string(i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

An `int` return type is unsuitable for two reasons (i) a leading zero is arbitrary, (ii) an `int` is vulnerable to overflow for a number of that magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it as an int, you can multiply the value and add it then:

```
int Common::digits() {
    int digits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        digits *= 10;
        digits += i;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

but this will only work for numbers smaller than 10, otherwise you have to get the decimal length of your number (how often can you divide by ten before getting 0 or something similar) multiply by 10^(that number) and can afterwards add.
Of course you will lose trailing zeros and will get the overflow quite fast as Bathsheba mentioned